# Codeigniter Array values Assign to Variables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have following data array returned by Item_model. This array included some values of MySQL tables columns such as 'r_qty' and 'ap_qty'.

```
$this->data['issueData']=$this->Item_model->ItemRequestfromHDData($id);
```

## Item_model

```
function ItemRequestfromHDData($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('store_update_stock.*,store_update_stock_details.*,tbl_user.username,store_item.*,
        sum(qty) as avqty, sum(store_update_stock_details.r_qty) as r_qty, 
        sum(store_update_stock_details.ap_qty) as ap_qty');
        $this->db->from('store_update_stock_details');
        $this->db->join('store_update_stock', 'store_update_stock.update_stock_id=store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_user', 'store_update_stock.supplier=tbl_user.userId');
        $this->db->join('store_item', 'store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id', 'left');        
        $this->db->where(array('store_update_stock.update_stock_id' => $id, 'store_update_stock_details.status' => 1));     
        $this->db->group_by('store_item.item_id');

        $q = $this->db->get();
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I want to assign these two columns / values to variables. I tried following assignments.

```
$r_qty = $data['r_qty'];
$ap_qty = $data['ap_qty'];
```

but didn't get the expected result. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please add model code also

Comment: I don't know what `$this->data` is. I also don't know what `$data` is. But I know they are not the same.

Comment: @ Anand Pandey. Pls. see my edit

Comment: @ Paul. Pls. see my edit

Comment: `$q->result()` returns an array of objects.  So, `$this->data['issueData']` is an array.  The 1st element in that array will be an object.  `$val = $this->data['issueData'][0]; $r_qty = $val->r_qty;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per codeigniter documentation,

> result()
>
> This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an
>   empty array on failure.

Typically you’ll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR Q enter code here QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```

So, your code should be

```
foreach ($this->data['issueData'] as $data)
{
    $r_qty = $data->r_qty;
    $ap_qty = $data->ap_qty;
}
```